# Homebrew looses track of Python

Tags: python, configuration, homebrew

Pior to my latest update of Homebrew (1.2.4) I had Python located, as indicated by `brew --config`, with a link to the latest Homebrew version:

```
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

and both this and the macOS system-provided Python were visible to `which -a`.

Following the update, I've lost access to this Python (though it still exists, and is available as `python2`) and just the old system-supplied Python is indicated by listed by `brew --config` as

```
Python: /usr/bin/python
```

and by `which -a`.

Is this the intended behavior of the latest Homebrew? If not, is there a fix for restoring the access I once had to the latest Homebrew Python?

---

Note that I also get the following results (which means I can't use `brew` to fix itself):

```
$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run python2
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run python
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run python3
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2
To relink: brew unlink python3 && brew link python3
```

---

Naively I assume I can fix this "by hand" with

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```

But I wonder, given that Homebrew has made such a profound change to the Python configuration, whether more is not going on (that such linking will break). After all, the latest update chose to *remove* this link when it was present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the intended ([though poorly documented](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/15746#issuecomment-316366008)) behavior.

To ensure access to the installed Python, it is now necessary to add `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` to your `PATH` either with

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

or by adding it to `/private/etc/path`.

This will restore access to not only `python`, but also `pip` and other Python-related tools, access to which also vanishes with this update. Access to all of these tools is now implemented through symlinks in `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin`:

```
2to3@ -> ../../bin/2to3-2
easy_install@ -> ../../bin/easy_install-2.7
idle@ -> ../../bin/idle2
pip@ -> ../../bin/pip2
pydoc@ -> ../../bin/pydoc2
python@ -> ../../bin/python2
python-config@ -> ../../bin/python2-config
pythonw@ -> ../../bin/pythonw2
smtpd.py@ -> ../../bin/smtpd2.py
```

---

Note that (without user intervention to change paths as described above) this update appears to violate [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/):

> The more general `python` command should be installed whenever any
>   version of Python 2 is installed and should invoke the same version of
>   Python as the `python2` command